# Sorting posts by custom fields in meta_query

Tags: custom-field, meta-query, order

How to apply 'order_by' in WordPress query in the following example:

I have a query to get all posts with custom field for event dates  greater or equal current date. I can have up to 10 event dates (event_date_0, event_date_1 etc) per post so I run a loop in meta query like:

```
$meta_query_array = array(
    'relation' => 'OR'
); 

for($date_row = 0;$date_row < 10; $date_row++){
    $single_date_query = array(
        'key'       => 'event_date_'.$date_row,
        'value'     => date('Y-m-d'),
        'compare'   => '>=',
        'type'      => 'DATE'
    );
    array_push($meta_query_array, $single_date_query);
}

$args = array(
    'post_type'         => array('events'),
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
    'meta_query'        => $meta_query_array
);

$events = new WP_Query( $args )
```

That part works fine. I get all posts where at least 1 of 10 event dates is greater or equal current date.

Now I need to apply sorting (order by). I'd like to set order_by by another custom field "rating" DESC. And this is where I fail.

Simply added to $args, like:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'         => array('events'),
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
    'meta_query'        => $meta_query_array,
    'meta_key'          => 'rating',
    'orderby'           => 'meta_value_num',
    'order'             => 'DESC',
);
```

is not working. Not sure how to push it to meta query, if need be.

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of WordPress 4.2, you can combine `meta_query` and `orderby`. The following example is taken from [make.wordpress.org](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2015/03/30/query-improvements-in-wp-4-2-orderby-and-meta_query/).

Example of a simple `meta_query`:

```
$q = new WP_Query( array(
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        'state_clause' => array(
            'key' => 'state',
            'value' => 'Wisconsin',
        ),
        'city_clause' => array(
            'key' => 'city',
            'compare' => 'EXISTS',
        ), 
    ),
    'orderby' => 'city_clause',
);
```

The `orderby` parameter just includes the key of your `meta_query`. You could also set it to `state_clause` for a different ordering.

What's really cool is the possibility to combine different order clauses by passing an array to `orderby`:

```
'orderby' => array(
    'city_clause' => 'ASC',
    'state_clause' => 'DESC',
),
```

This would translate to a SQL query like

```
ORDER BY city_clause ASC, state_clause DESC
```

for more complex ordering types.

Comment: It all would work great if only I could have 'relation' => 'AND' - however, in my case I need to have 'OR' - So in SQL it would look sth. like: "SELECT * FROM `events`  WHERE event_date_0 >= CURDATE() OR event_date_1 >= CURDATE() OR ... event_date_9 >= CURDATE() ORDER BY `rating` DESC